# Select from :LOV report / Using LOV as table_name bind variable

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a page which has a list of values (`P2_LIST`) and a region which displays the contents of the table based upon the table name in this list
e.g.

```
select * from :P2_LIST
```

however I can't save it as I get:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 21: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

`P2_LIST` is a LOV with a list containing valid table names only.

Is there a way to do this?

When I do select `P2_LIST` from dual I can see it holds the correct `TABLE_NAME` and if I hardcode the table names then it returns also.

The idea is I can then add more tables to this page simply by adding an entry to the shared component.

If this can be resolved my next part is I want to use a concatenated value for this too:

e.g. If I have two tables:

- thisistable_1 - submit thisistable
- thisisnottable_1 - submit thisisnottable

Then I want to use something along the lines of:

```
select * from :P2_LIST||_1
```

that way I can use the same LOV elsewhere.

I am running: Application Express 5.0.3.00.03

Comment: So your LOV contains names of a tables, you want to choose a table from a list, and select data from it? It won't work like this.

Comment: Why isn't it possible? can I not create a function / procedure which does this? I don't want to have multiple regions, I want a single region which can refresh.  create table test (col1 varchar2(2000));
insert into test VALUES ('TEST');
insert into test VALUES ('TEST2');    LOV = TEST / TEST2  region = report and query = select * from test where col1 = :P3_NEW . this works fine, but not where P3_NEW is the bind variable.

Comment: Yes, you can create a pipelined function, but inside this function you need to use `dbms_sql` package to describe columns and fetch data. As for me - too much efforts when more simple solution exists. May be if you have 100+ tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a dynamic SQL query.

Instead of `select * from :P2_LIST` define the report like this:

```
declare
   q long;
begin
   q := 'select * from ' || :P2_LIST || ';';
   return q;
end;
```

You'll also need to:

- check the "Use Generic Column Names (parse query at runtime only)" setting under the region source
- ensure that the source type is "SQL query (PL/SQL function body returning SQL query)"
- set the Headings Type to "Column Names (InitCap)"

(NB `long` in PL/SQL is a subtype defined as `varchar2(32760)` that I just use to save typing!)

Here's a quick demo: [apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=22644:10](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=22644:10)

Comment: Your demo looks exactly what I want, however I can't seem to get mine to work. I get: failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-00911: invalid character       for the number of column headings does it matter what I chose? I chose 5 (for these tables only have 5), but can I choose a smaller / larger number and it will resize accordingly?.  Is it possible you could export this page so I can compare the differences?

Comment: I left the number of columns at the default of 60.  The "Use Generic Column Names (parse query at runtime only)" option should prevent you getting the error when saving the report.

Comment: I can't import the page and there doesn't seem to be an easy work around. Could you export the app (which should work) for me please? On my editor page I see the 'Use generic columns' button, but it doesn't have the parse query at runtime option?  Here are my settings: http://i63.tinypic.com/259l36b.png

Comment: Here is an app export with just that page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve1tx8hb369xf1s/f31257.sql?dl=0

Comment: I found that although I specified "Generic column names" when creating the region, I had to set it again by updating the region after creation - APEX bug?

Comment: I wasn't able to look at your settings as that URL is blocked where I work.

Comment: Thanks. I've just managed to import it and run it (you had the list from the sql query, but i created the LOV and changed it and it's working fine too). I'll go through the pages now and see what I was missing and I'll post my results.

Comment: I was curious what would happen if you had a table with more than 60 columns, so I tried it.  When you select that table in the report APEX just displays the text "A maximum of 60 columns can be selected."

Comment: I've managed to find out why I was getting thr sql error. The reason is for each column 'sortable' should be set to 'No' for them all. If you choose a smaller number of generic columns than there are more in the table then: 'A maximum of 1 columns can be selected.' is displayed. The wizard for the report does ask whether to sort column or not, but I didn't use it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest here only following. Create a region for each table, then in region properties on the `Conditions` tab select

- `Condition Type` - `Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 = Expression 2`
- `Expression 1` - `P2_LIST` (without a colon)
- `Expression 2` - name of a table in this region

After submit your page will show result of a query of a selected table.